# Why increment id changes by large value?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, orders, increment-id

I have used **increment id** for loading and saving orders in my magento stores since long. I've seen it change it's value from **`124` to `2000000004`** between **two consecutive orders**. What I do not understand is why is there a need to jump it's value by so much?

Comment: How many storeviews are available in your magento?. Because each storeviews have separate serial incremental Ids.

Comment: I have 3 store view.

Answer (score 3):

The left most digit (most significant digit) is for mentioning the store from which the order was placed. I think you have more than one stores configured in your admin panel and the two orders are coming from different stores. That is why the left most digit (most significant digit) changed.

Comment: Good answer. But each storeviews have changed the left digit.

Comment: If it is helpful, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Brother I have already upvoted your answer.

Comment: I 'm the only one making purchase in this local project. So I'm sure that I've not changed the store view.

Comment: @Anime If there are no customisation in the Order number generation part, then this is when Magento will change the left most digit (most significant digit). If you did any customisation in order number generation part, then it depends on the implemented business logic.

Comment: @stalinrajindian Sorry, I didn't notice :) Thank you anyway !!

Comment: @N.KarthicKannan , I have not done any customisatin in order number generation part as well.